# AWS S3 <-> MS Onedrive sync with rules

Tags: sync, onedrive, amazon-s3

Is it possible to have an automatic synchronization between a specific AWS S3 bucket and a OneDrive folder ? and to specify rules e.g. remove certain files extensions from the sync ; only sync specific sub-directories ( to make an analogy with github, it's kind of .gitignore file )

Thanks